# Can I mix domain and local accounts on the same PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, windows-domain, microsoft-account

I have Windows 10 installed on my private Laptop. I am using Microsoft account to log in.

Sometimes I need to do some work-stuff on it. At work, we have Active Domain with roaming profiles set up, so we can basically work from any PC in the Network.

I would like to add my domain user to my private PC, so that when I am in the company's network I can use my Laptop for work and access my roaming profile.

At home I would use my private account as usual.

Is this kind of configuration possible in Win 10? Are there some considerations I haven't think of?

Comment: Did you check with your system admin at the office ? Many companies have policies that explicitly forbid using private devices in their domain. And you need the assistance of the domain admin anyway to add your computer to the domain. That is not something a regular user can do.

Comment: It is a small company. I am impromptu system admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have two such logins, but be aware that these will be two separate user
accounts, where one will not have the permissions needed to access the
files and folders of the other. Unless you wish to totally separate the files
of the two accounts, extra work is needed to grant permissions on both sides.

The permissions are granted by one user via right-click on the folder,
Properties, Security tab, Advanced button, Change Permissions button,
then add the other user.